# Run NestJS application using app.js (express)

Tags: node.js, express, npm, nestjs

I have a NestJS application that starts fine with:

*npm start* (npm run start:prod)
or
*node dist/main*

However, I want to use app.js and can't figure out how to configure the app.js file to accomplish this.

app.js file

```
var serverType = 'AM-API-MDD';
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3030;

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-client-key, x-client-token, x-client-secret, Authorization");
    next();
    });


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/'));

//body parse
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb',extended: true }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}))
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('dist/main.js', { root: __dirname });
});

// Handle 404
app.use(function(req, res) {
    //res.send(‘404: Page not Found’, 404);
    res.status(404).send({status:404, message: '404 Not Found', type:'client'}); 
   });

// Handle 500
app.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500).send({status:500, message: 'internal error', type:'internal'}); 
   });

//listen
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port,() => console.log(serverType +' server running on port: '+ port));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What about this `app.js` file do you want to use? This looks like a regular Express application to me, what about it do you need to use with Nest?

Comment: I'd like to be able to run 'node app.js' and start the application. 
 - node-windows creates a windows service that autostarts the application.

Comment: So why not make an `app.js` script in the project root tat imports `dist/main`? Make sure to compile the project first and you should be good to go. Otherwise Nest's CLI has a `start --watch` mode that can be ran via npm scripts `start:dev` and it will auto-recompile and restart the server on file change

Comment: If you have suggestions on how to make the app.js do this, great?  I'm open to suggestions. 
 - Nest's 'start --watch' is fine if you're running from a command line, but I want this to be able to run from an automated process, when/if Windows reboots? 

I don't want to have to open a prompt and run the script.

node-windows will create a service that autoruns "node app.js" (or "node server.js")   

So, I guess ultimately, I need to script file that node can call which runs "npm start"

Answer (score 0):

trying to get app.js is the wrong approach.

*node dist/main.js* runs the application - so the startup script is the main.js file.

node-windows can reference the main.js file, rather than the app.js file.

Thanks to Jay McDoniel for pushing me in the right direction.